# Can I say 無理しないでください when asking someone to not bother too much?

Tags: phrases

Can I say "無理しないでください" to someone who wants to bring me a gift, but I want to tell him that something small is ok and not to bother too much?
Or is there something else that would sound better?
We are friends, so it shouldn't sound too formal

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 無理しないでください

sounds bit too formal between friends.

> 無理しないでいいよ

make it more casual and put this in addition to it.

> そんなに気使わないでもいいよ。

***"You do not have to look after me that much."*** or literal translation of ***"please do not bother too much."***

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it :)